# "Could not load Notifications preference pane"

Tags: macos, error, system-settings

Preference panes generally load fine for a while after I boot up my MacBook, but eventually I start getting errors like "Could not load Notifications preference pane" (replace "Notifications" with whatever; it's the same for all panes). Quitting (or force-quitting) and relaunching *System Preferences* does not help.

Here's what seems like relevant messages from the system log:

```
default 14:23:37.347340+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    FRONTLOGGING: version 1
default 14:23:37.347384+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registering, pid=88357
default 14:23:37.349235+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    CHECKIN: pid=88357
default 14:23:37.359653+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    CHECKEDIN: pid=88357 asn=0x0-0x3ea9ea60 foreground=0
error   14:23:37.360730+0100    runningboardd   Could not rationalize xpc service at: /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Notifications.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice.xpc
default 14:23:37.391799+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registered, pid=88357 ASN=0x0,0x3ea9ea60
default 14:23:37.391978+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registered, pid=88357 cgConnectionID=36b47f
default 14:23:37.394478+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Current system appearance, (HLTB: 1), (SLS: 0)
default 14:23:37.398621+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Post-registration system appearance: (HLTB: 1)
default 14:23:37.421147+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    MacOS error: -67065
default 14:23:37.422301+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    *** Assertion failure in int NSViewServiceApplicationMain(int, const char **)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-464.1/NSViewServiceApplication.m:1382
default 14:23:37.422755+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    main caught NSInternalInconsistencyException: 'failed to obtain security code reference for process 88349 due to error -67065' with user dictionary (null) and call stack (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2c67c8ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62936805 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2c6a5d10 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff2eddcaf7 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff5efab95f NSViewServiceApplicationMain + 1481
    5   PreferencePanes                     0x00007fff37495176 PreferencePaneMain + 179
    6   com.apple.preference.notifications. 0x0000000105107cb2 main + 40
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff63ca47fd start + 1
    8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
default 14:23:37.424953+0100    System Preferences  ### Error:Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "could not obtain endpoint for com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice/com.apple.systempreferences; look for logging from service, launchd, taskgated, etc." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=could not obtain endpoint for com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice/com.apple.systempreferences; look for logging from service, launchd, taskgated, etc.} File:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/PrefPanesFramework/PrefPanesFramework-374/NSVBProxyPreferencePane.m Line:28
default 14:23:47.463155+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    FRONTLOGGING: version 1
default 14:23:47.463193+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registering, pid=88359
default 14:23:47.464981+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    CHECKIN: pid=88359
default 14:23:47.474823+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    CHECKEDIN: pid=88359 asn=0x0-0x3ea9fa61 foreground=0
error   14:23:47.475827+0100    runningboardd   Could not rationalize xpc service at: /System/Library/PreferencePanes/Notifications.prefPane/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice.xpc
default 14:23:47.507615+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registered, pid=88359 ASN=0x0,0x3ea9fa61
default 14:23:47.507813+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Registered, pid=88359 cgConnectionID=313b3f
default 14:23:47.510595+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Current system appearance, (HLTB: 1), (SLS: 0)
default 14:23:47.515577+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    Post-registration system appearance: (HLTB: 1)
default 14:23:47.537616+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    MacOS error: -67065
default 14:23:47.538716+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    *** Assertion failure in int NSViewServiceApplicationMain(int, const char **)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ViewBridge/ViewBridge-464.1/NSViewServiceApplication.m:1382
default 14:23:47.539175+0100    com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice    main caught NSInternalInconsistencyException: 'failed to obtain security code reference for process 88349 due to error -67065' with user dictionary (null) and call stack (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2c67c8ab __exceptionPreprocess + 250
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff62936805 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2c6a5d10 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 88
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff2eddcaf7 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] + 166
    4   ViewBridge                          0x00007fff5efab95f NSViewServiceApplicationMain + 1481
    5   PreferencePanes                     0x00007fff37495176 PreferencePaneMain + 179
    6   com.apple.preference.notifications. 0x000000010a199cb2 main + 40
    7   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff63ca47fd start + 1
    8   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
default 14:23:47.541805+0100    System Preferences  ### advanceToConfigPhaseIfNeeded error :Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "could not obtain endpoint for com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice/com.apple.view-bridge; look for logging from service, launchd, taskgated, etc." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=could not obtain endpoint for com.apple.preference.notifications.remoteservice/com.apple.view-bridge; look for logging from service, launchd, taskgated, etc.}
```

I've seen lots of reports of errors like this before, but given my specific circumstances (basically they always work after initially rebooting, but inevitably cease working) and the specific log messages, I thought it was worth another question. Any thoughts on how to resolve this permanently?

Comment: I've had this since upgrading to 10.15 on my iMac; 90% of my sysprefs don't open. Same error -67065, which apparently means `errSecCSNoSuchCode` which means "Code signing host has no guest code with the requested attributes", and I have no idea what THAT means...